# Squished circles

Tags: geometry-generator

I'm looking to squish some circles while maintaining the area.

Initially I buffer a circle from centre. This gives an area.

I want the area to be affected by an influence from North, East, South or West.

In this example, X is a northern influence.

The effect of X flattens the northern face by x and squashes the area out the south of the circle.

Has anyone seen or done anything similar?

I've projecting lines into polygons, smoothing them and then using union and combine - but it feels like it's getting majorly messy. I can make a circle in this way, that I can influence, but it's just not mathematically correct.

[image]

Comment: What software are you using, QGIS, ARCGIS, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

This task does not have analytical solution or it is extremely complex and requires finding root of non-linear equation. Numeric algorithm is simple. First extend split line significantly in both directions. Make sure line goes W->E.

1. Define lower and upper (low,high) limits for radius of new circle
2. Compute mid = (low+high)/2
3. Compute circle with radius = mid and cut it by split line. This results in 2 polygons. You need **second**.
4. If second.area < targetArea:low = mid else high = mid
5. If (high-low)<tolerance (1 mm?) **second** is your shape, break. Otherwise goto 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression, where in the first three lines, you can define the size of the initial radius (white and blue circular segments), distance h (hight of blue segment) as well as the new radius (outer line of red ring). To find this last value, a trial and error approach would be the most practical way to do so (see below for details and how to find this values in an easy and fast way).

```
with_variable ('init_radius',8,
with_variable ('new_radius',10.6956,  -- the get equal area, change this value (see below)
with_variable ('h',7,
    difference (
        difference (
        buffer ($geometry, @new_radius,22),
        bounds(
            make_line (
                project (project ($geometry, @init_radius-@h,0), -2*@new_radius, radians (90)),
                project (project ($geometry, @init_radius-@h,0), -2*@new_radius, radians (270)),
                project ($geometry, @new_radius, 0))
            )
       ), buffer ($geometry, @init_radius,22)
))))
```

[image]

---

Edit: to caclulate `new_radius`, based on `init_radius` and `h`, based on the [area formula for cirular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), you should solve this equation:

```
@init_radius^2 * pi + 
(@init_radius^2 * acos * (1- h/@init_radius) - (@init_radius-h) * sqrt (@init_radius^2 - (@init_radius-h)^2))
=
(@new_radius^2 * acos * (1- h/@new_radius) - (@new_radius-h) * sqrt (@new_radius^2 - (@new_radius-h)^2))
```

### Pragmatic (heuristic) solution

As this is quite complex, as mentioned by @FelixIP, there is no easy way to do so and you should consider how large the effort should be and how precise the result should be. A pragmatic an probably the most efficient solution that can still be as accurate as you want it to be would be trial and error.

Set a label with the following expression. It calculates the area of the blue and the red polygons. Change `new_radius` in line two as long until the two areas have the same value - you can see the changes in realtime at the preview at the bottom when you change `new radius`, so this is great to immediately see how changing the values affects the area and you can in realtime increase/decrease the value until it fits - probably the fastest/most efficient way to find a solution. In line 4, change to number of digits for rounding the area calculation:

[image]

```
with_variable ('init_radius',8,
with_variable ('new_radius',10.6956,
with_variable ('h',7,
with_variable('round',2,  -- number of digits to round the calculated area
'blue area: '  ||  
round (
    area(
        intersection (
        buffer ($geometry, @init_radius,22),
        bounds(
            make_line (
                project (project ($geometry, @init_radius-@h,0), -2*@init_radius, radians (90)),
                project (project ($geometry, @init_radius-@h,0), -2*@init_radius, radians (270)),
                project ($geometry, @init_radius, 0))
            )
       )
    ), 
    @round
)
||  '\n'  || 
'red area: '  || 
round (
    area (
        difference (
            difference (
                buffer ($geometry, @new_radius,22),
                    bounds(
                        make_line (
                            project (project ($geometry, @init_radius-@h,0), -2*@new_radius, radians (90)),
                            project (project ($geometry, @init_radius-@h,0), -2*@new_radius, radians (270)),
                            project ($geometry, @new_radius, 0)
                        )
                    )
                ), 
                buffer ($geometry, @init_radius,22)
            )
        ),@round
        )
))))
```

Comment: Key word here 'maintaining the area', so his question is how to find 'large'.

Comment: See edited answer